# Remote Desktop Client on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to have a RDP client on Windows Server 2012

But still no success, I don't understand why something that easy is so cumbersome on winserver 2012

I just need to install the feature to connect myself to another win server 2012 which is on aws

You know, that software that executes a little window where you put address and password then connect to remote host?

How can I achieve this on winserver 2012?

I've read somewhere that it isn't available on this microsft platform, I can't believe that...

Any ideas?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: It should be available by default, though? I’m not aware of any way to not have it (unless using Server Core). Simply execute `mstsc`. Also, you should perhaps provide your sources. “read somewhere” isn’t helping us tell if you perhaps misjudged the context or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bunch of options :)

- Win + R OR Win + X -> Run   OR   right-click on start button -> Run and then type `mstsc`
- press the start button and then search for `remote desktop`